# Laravel 5.6 Eloquent Relations level 2

Tags: php, laravel

[image: How to get all of the data on this picture.]

How to get all of the data on this picture. Im using Laravel 5.6 Eloquent Model.

Answer (score 1):

Keep the columns being named as what you wrote in the relation chart, and name the tables as *years, depts, candidates*, then define **Year hasMany Dept**, and **hasMany Candidate**:

```
class Year extends Model
{    
    public function depts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Dept');
    }

    public function candidates()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Candidate');
    }
}
```

Then you can take them all by **with** method, in Controller:

```
$years = App\Year::with(['depts', 'candidates'])->get();
```

**UPDATE**

Candidate can also be the main model by applying *Nested Eager Loading*.

make sure you've defined Candidate and Dept first:

**Candidate Model**

```
class Candidate extends Model
{    
    public function Year()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Year');
    }
}
```

**Dept Model**

```
class Dept extends Model
{    
    public function Year()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Year');
    }
}
```

**In Controller**

```
$candidates = App\Candidate::with('year.depts')->get();
```

Comment: I want to make the candidate as the main model.

Comment: I just updated my answer, please check and let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should first understand the [relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships) with laravel model.

i tried to map the relation. let me know if i am wrong.

here i think:

- a candidate have one year
- one year have multiple candidate
- one year belongs to one department (this part confusing)

**Department Model**

```
class Department extends Model
{
    public function years(){
        return $this->hasMany(Year::class,'dept_id');
    }
}
```

**Year Model:**

```
class Year extends Model
{
    public function department(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Department::class,'dept_id');
    }

    public function candidates(){
        return $this->hasMany(Candidate::class,'year_id', 'year_id');
    }
}
```

**Candidate Model:**

```
class Candidate extends Model
{
    public function year(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Year::class,'year_id','year_id');
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
 public function index()
    {
        $data = Year::with(['department', 'candidate'])->get();
        dd($data);
    }
```